# How to add two <map> with different URL links to the <onclick> image?

Tags: html, image, url, onclick

I tried to add two `<map>` to "HomeNewProducts1.png" but without any success. The two `<map>` URL links should go to two different landing pages. I am new to Javascript. Please kindly help!!! Thank you!

```
<div>
<img src="images/NewProductsBox1.png" class="img-responsive" 
id="newProduct" onclick="changeImage()" 
onmouseover="this.src='images/NewProductsBoxOpen1.png';" 
onmouseout="this.src='images/NewProductsBox1.png'; map name="map1"/>
</div>

<map name="map1">
 <area href="function changeImage() {
    newProduct.src = "images/HomeNewProducts1.png";
    }" shape="circle" coords="240,180,140">
 <area href="function changeImage() {
    newProduct.src = "images/HomeNewProducts1.png";
    }" shape="rect" coords="4,6,88,69" href="#">
</map>

<script>
function changeImage() {
    newProduct.src = "images/HomeNewProducts1.png";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. On first try of the code, the hover changes the image.

Comment: Still no idea what you are trying to accomplish. There's two href's on the second area. I don't understand all of the image swapping. I don't think putting "function" in an href works. Please reply ifyou still need help or figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: @paulmz  Thank you for your response. I tried to do the effect that hover the first image "imageNewProductsBox1.png" to show the second image "NewProductsBoxOpen1.png". Then click on the second image to show the third image "HomeNewProducts1.png" which with two links that clickable to link to the two different landing pages.

Answer (score 0):

Okay- still trying to wrap my head around what you're trying to accomplish and if this is the best approach. I think you're overcomplicating the area tags. So far, this works, but I'm not sure if it's entirely what you're looking for:

```
<div>
<img src="images/NewProductsBox1.png" class="img-responsive" 
id="newProduct" onclick="changeImage()" onmouseover="this.src='images/NewProductsBoxOpen1.png';" 
onmouseout="this.src='images/NewProductsBox1.png';" usemap="map1" />
</div>

<map name="map1">
 <area shape="circle" coords="240,180,140" href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank" />
 <area shape="rect" coords="4,6,88,69" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" />
</map>

<script>
function changeImage() {
    newProduct.src = "images/HomeNewProducts1.png";
    }
</script>
```